# Running Locust Tasks Distributed Mode

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, distributed, locust

I am currently running a master node and 4 slaves (all on separate AWS instances). Each instance belongs to the same VPC. The master node belongs to a separate security group. My application's interface server binds to port 8001 (as in host:port). I am using this sample command line for a slave:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --slave --master-host=192.168.16.136 --master-port=5557
```

Here is my actual simple Taskset (really basic): https://gist.github.com/ahlusar1989/4c6abb0463197401660073ab837f24b3

I am not receiving any results, even after I receive the confirmation: `[2016-10-18 20:39:12,688] ip-192-168-16-136/INFO/locust.runners: Sending hatch jobs to 4 ready clients`

I am clearly missing something with the host and IP not properly binding within each instance. Should I be specifying the host within the User class? I would appreciate any and all feedback on next steps. Please do not hesitate to ask for clarification and I will only gladly oblige to your request.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.9. I am not sure how this would affect the aforementioned question.